# React Testing-Library Cannot Find A Dynamic FieldArray Input

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

I am trying to write tests for a web app page in Typescript using React, and I have hit a roadblock on testing the submit button. To submit, a user needs to fill in all required fields. One of these fields is the email of clients, which can range between 1 client and 10 clients. I am using userEvents to type into the inputs, but when I try to type into the email input I get the error "TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the placeholder text of: Email".

I attempted to use async and waitFor to wait for the dynamic email input to load, but that resulted in the same error. It is not a conditional element, as there will always be at least one input with the placeholder text "Email". I am stuck hard on what to do.

The test code:

```
test("Render the page and check if submission with all required values works.",() => {
    {/*Render the CreateRequest page*/}
    render(<CreateRequest3/>);
    {/*Fill in a sample title input*/}
    userEvent.type(screen.getByPlaceholderText("Title"),"Test Title");
    // {/*Fill in a sample client input*/}
    userEvent.type(screen.getByPlaceholderText("Email"),"test@test.ca");
    {/*Fill in a sample title input*/}
    userEvent.type(screen.getByPlaceholderText("Language"),"English");
    {/*Check the terms and conditions checkbox*/}
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole("checkbox",{name:"Accept the terms and conditions"}));
    {/*Simulate the user clicking on the submit button*/}
    fireEvent.submit(screen.getByRole("form"));
    {/*Check if onSubmit did not call, as not all required fields are present*/}
    expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

The code for the dynamic email input:

```
<div id="requestClients">
  <Label>Client(s)</Label>
  {fields.map((field, index) => (
    <div key={field.id} className="flex pt-1 gap-1">
      {/*added by jan*/}
      <div className="flex-col flex-1">
      <Input
        className=""
        placeholder="Email"
        maxLength={320}
        aria-invalid={
          errors.clients?.[index]?.value ? "true" : "false"
        }
        {...register(`clients.${index}.value`, {
          required: true,
        })}
        value={clientList[index].client}
        onChange={(e) => handleClientChange(e, index)}
      />
      {errors.clients?.[index]?.value &&
        errors.clients?.[index]?.value?.type === "required" && (
          <p role="alert" className=" text-red-500 text-xs">
            This field is required!
          </p>
        )}
        </div>
      {0 === index && fields.length < 10 && (
        <Button type="button" onClick={handleClientAdd}>
          <Plus />
        </Button>
      )}
      {0 != index && fields.length > 1 && (
        <Button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => handleClientRemove(index)}
        >
          <X />
        </Button>
      )}
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```